# Current Date in where clause

Tags: firebird

How do I put current date into the where clause without having to type it in all the time?

```
Select SALEITEMS.SKU,
       STOCK.SHORTDESC,
       SALEITEMS.SALEPRICEEX,                    
       SALEITEMS.COSTPRICEEX,
       SUM(((SALEITEMS.SALEPRICEEX - SALEITEMS.COSTPRICEEX) / 
             SALEITEMS.SALEPRICEEX) * 100) AS GP    
  From SALEITEMS
 Inner Join STOCK On SALEITEMS.SKU = STOCK.SKU 
 where SALEITEMS.FP_DATE = '13 Nov 2018'
 group by 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `current_date`:

```
where SALEITEMS.FP_DATE = current_date
```

This assumes that `FP_DATE` has the data type `DATE` .

If `FP_DATE` is a `timestamp` column, then the above will only return rows where the time part of the column is `00:00:00`. To ignore the time part you could cast the column to a `date` value:

```
where cast(SALEITEMS.FP_DATE as date) = current_date
```

That however will not make use of an index on the column so it might not be fast enough. In that case the usual approach is to use a range query:

```
where SALEITEMS.FP_DATE >= current_date
  and SALEITEMS.FP_DATE < current_date + 1
```

`current_date + 1` is "tomorrow" (at midnight)

Comment: If I do that then it displays nothing. If I select between 2 dates then I get an output

Comment: I think that fp_date is a timestamp field

Comment: @KevinGoosen: see my edit